# GroupBy item and Sum Quantities of items

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, group-by, count

I have an array of orders within each order is an array of items. How do I group all the orders by item name  and get the sum total of items ordered. In this case output would be :

**Output**

```
Item01 : quantity = 2;
Item02 : quantity = 45;
```

**GetOrders**

```
public Order[] GetOrders()
{
   Order[] orders = new Order[]
      {
         new Order
            {
               id = 1,
               orderLines = new OrderLine[]
                  {
                     new OrderLine
                        {
                           itemName = "Item 01",
                           quantity = 1
                        },
                     new OrderLine
                        {
                           itemName = "Item 02",
                           quantity = 3
                        },
                  },
            },
         new Order
            {
               id = 2,
               orderLines = new OrderLine[]
                  {
                     new OrderLine
                        {
                           itemName = "Item 01",
                           quantity = 1
                        },
                     new OrderLine
                        {
                           itemName = "Item 02",
                           quantity = 42
                        }
                  }
            }
      };
      ...
```

**I tried the following:**

```
foreach (var order in orders)
{
   foreach (var orderline in order.orderLines.GroupBy(x => x.itemName).Select(group => new
      {
         Metric = group.Key,
         Count = group.Count()
      }))

   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", orderline.Metric, orderline.Count);
   }
}
```

but it just returns  1 for each item. I am relatively new to programming , so be easy on me.Thanks

Comment: You'll have to start with a [SelectMany()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) to flatten the sublists into a single enumerable. Then you can do your grouping, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the sum total of all items ordered, use the following query:

```
var results = 
    (from order in orders
    from orderLine in order.orderLines
    group orderLine by orderLine.itemName into orderLineGrouping
    let totalQuantity = orderLineGrouping.Sum(ol => ol.quantity)
    select new { itemName = orderLineGrouping.Key, metric = totalQuantity }).ToList();

results.ForEach(resultItem => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", resultItem.itemName, resultItem.metric);
```

Comment: This doesn't actually give me  results it gives me this as "results" System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,WarehouseOptimization.OrderLine],<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,System.Int32]]

Comment: I've edited the answer to make sure that it displays the values in a similar way to the way you tried in your question.

Comment: Thanks !! it works with a small edit. This was my first question and I got great answers immediately. Not sure If I can can make this an answer with 1 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

1. Flatten orderlines
2. group the item name and quantities for output string
3. Select the output string using grouped key and sum of grouped quantities

See code:

```
var output = orders.SelectMany(x => x.orderLines)
    .GroupBy(x => x.itemName, x => x.quantity)
    .Select(x => $"{x.Key} : quantity = {x.Sum(y => y)}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Flatten `OrderLines`

You need to familiarise your self with [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) its one of the most useful methods around

> **SelectMany**, from LINQ, collapses many elements into a single
>   collection. The resulting collection is of another element type. We
>   specify how an element is transformed into a collection of other
>   elements.

```
var summary = orders.Where(x => x.OrderLines != null) // Check for null as there seems to be null orderlines in your model
                    .SelectMany(x => x.OrderLines)  // Flatten
                    .GroupBy(x => x.itemName)       // Group
                    .Select(group => new            // Project
                              {
                                 ItemName = group.Key,
                                 TotalQuantity = group.Sum(x => x.quantity)
                              })
                    .ToList();                      // To List
```

---

***Tip*** : use appropriate casing for `itemName` and `quantity`

[Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> The following table summarizes the capitalization rules for
>   identifiers and provides examples for the different types of
>   identifiers.

[image]

Sorry my [OCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) just kicked in

Comment: There is is a system.NullArguementexception on the .selectMany

Comment: @AmetureBoss Did that fix your problem?

Comment: @Sarumen , I think You meant Where(x => x.OrderLines != null) not Where(x => OrderLines != null).

Comment: I think I was not clear I need to add the count of the quantities, so in this ex. item 2 would be 45 not 2. Your answer groups the items and adds the amount of Individual items.